# How to convert int array to hex string

Tags: java, android, string, int, hex

I want to convert an `int` array to a hex string. I am unsure if I am doing this correctly.

I create an `int[]` in another class and get it with *via* `msg.obj`. I am getting some values in Hex but am unsure if they are correct.

```
int[] readBuf = (int[]) msg.obj; //int array is in another class 
StringBuffer output=new StringBuffer();
for (int a:readBuf) {
    int val1 = a & 0xff;
    output.append(Integer.toHexString(val1));
}   
dataView.setText(output);
```

Comment: How would you like to convert your int array to hex string? Could you post example of input with expected output (preferably with explanation with why such output would be expected)?

Comment: `int val1 = a & 0xff;`You throw away three bytes of every int.

Comment: any suggestion in the code ??? plz.

Comment: You really need to show some input/output examples. e.g. "this array: {1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, ..., 0x1000_0000} should become the string 'bfafbfafbfaf'"

Comment: I am getting this int array (one value at every second from remote device) [I@42b4f660
              [I@42b76a40
             [I@42b7a368
             and so on...

Comment: @Omar. Those are the results of `arr.toString`, to see the actual array contents, such as the length and examples of the `int`s inside the array you need `System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(arr))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Malt's answer definitely highlights the problem with your code: that it doesn't 0-pad the `int` hex values; and that you mask the int to only take the last 8 bits using `a & 0xff`. Your original question implies you are only after the last `byte` in each `int`, but it really isn't clear.

You say you get results every second from your remote object. On a slow machine with large arrays it is possible that it could take a significant number of milliseconds to convert a long `int[]` to a hex string using your method using your (or rather Malt's corrected version of your) method.

A much faster method would be to get each 4-bit [nibble](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble) from each int using bit shifting, and get the appropriate hex character from a static hex lookup array (*note this does base-16 encoding, you would get shorter strings from something like base-64 encoding*):

```
public class AltConverter {
    final protected static char[] encoding = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();
    public String convertToString(int[] arr) {
        char[] encodedChars = new char[arr.length * 4 * 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            int v = arr[i];
            int idx = i * 4 * 2;
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                encodedChars[idx + j] = encoding[(v >>> ((7-j)*4)) & 0x0F];
            }
        }
        return new String(encodedChars);
    }
}
```

<s>Testing this vs your original method using [caliper](https://code.google.com/p/caliper/) (microbenchmark [results here](https://microbenchmarks.appspot.com/runs/be15aeb9-9c0e-4af9-8eea-6748462bb324#r:scenario.benchmarkSpec.parameters.sutFactory&c:scenario.benchmarkSpec.parameters.N)) shows this is around 11x faster <sup>†</sup> (caveat: on my machine). **EDIT** For anyone interested in running this and comparing the results, there is a [gist here](https://gist.github.com/AGBrown/48b25ec4fee0a5884383) with the source code.</s>

<s>Even for a single element array</s>

*The original microbenchmark used [Caliper](https://code.google.com/p/caliper/) as I happened to be trying it out at the time. I have rewritten it to use [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/). While doing so I found that the [results I linked to](https://microbenchmarks.appspot.com/runs/be15aeb9-9c0e-4af9-8eea-6748462bb324#r:scenario.benchmarkSpec.parameters.sutFactory&c:scenario.benchmarkSpec.parameters.N) and copied here originally used an array that was only ever filled with `0` for each `int` element. This caused the JVM to optimise the `AltConverter` code for arrays with length > `1` yielding artificial 10x to 11x improvements in `AltConverter` vs `SimpleConverter`. JMH and Caliper produce very similar results for both the flawed and corrected benchmark. (Updated benchmark project for maven eclipse [here](https://github.com/AGBrown/SO-intarrtostring)).*

This is around 2x to 4x faster depending on array length (*on my machine™*). The mean runtime results (in ns) are:

```
Average run times in nanoseconds
Original method: SimpleConverter
New method: AltConverter
 | N          |    Alt / ns | error / ns | Simple / ns | Error / ns | Speed up |
 | ---------: |  ---------: | ---------: | ----------: | ---------: | -------: |
 | 1          |          30 |          1 |          61 |          2 |     2.0x |
 | 100        |         852 |         19 |       3,724 |         99 |     4.4x |
 | 1000       |       7,517 |        200 |      36,484 |        879 |     4.9x |
 | 1000,0     |      82,641 |      1,416 |     360,670 |      5,728 |     4.4x |
 | 1000,00    |   1,014,612 |    241,089 |   4,006,940 |     91,870 |     3.9x |
 | 1000,000   |   9,929,510 |    174,006 |  41,077,214 |  1,181,322 |     4.1x |
 | 1000,000,0 | 182,698,229 | 16,571,654 | 432,730,259 | 13,310,797 |     2.4x |
```

<sup>†</sup> *Disclaimer: Micro-benchmarking is dangerous to rely on as an indication of performance in a real world app, but caliper is a good benchmarking framework, jmh is imho better. A performance difference of <s>10x</s> 4x, with <s>very small standard deviation, in caliper</s> a good t-test result is enough to indicate a good performance increase even inside a more complex application*.

Comment: There is also a maven-based eclipse project at https://github.com/AGBrown/SO-intarrtostring for anyone interested in comparing the performance using caliper.

Comment: Thanks for the detail answer. I have tried your method and its work.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I understand your intention, there are two problems with the code:

1. `int val1 = a & 0xff;`
   You're taking only the last byte of your int. If you want to convert the whole integer, remove the `&0xff`.
2. You want to makes sure that the output of `Integer.toHexString` is always padded with zeroes in front so it's length is always 8 characters (since every byte of the 4 byte long int requres 2 characters). Otherwise both array `{1,2,3}` and the array `{291}` will give you the same string - `123`.

here's a quick and dirty working code example

```
    public static String byteToUnsignedHex(int i) {
        String hex = Integer.toHexString(i);
        while(hex.length() < 8){
            hex = "0" + hex; 
        }
        return hex;
    }

    public static String intArrToHex(int[] arr) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(arr.length * 8);
        for (int b : arr) {
            builder.append(byteToUnsignedHex(b));
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(intArrToHex(new int[]{1,2,3}));
        System.out.println(intArrToHex(new int[]{291}));
        System.out.println(intArrToHex(new int[]{0xFFFFFFFF}));
    }
```

Output:

```
000000010000000200000003
00000123
ffffffff
```

Comment: Thanks Malt for your quick help. I will try to implement your strategy :)